# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

i never used maven before. But i always want to. I update one eclipse project im working on to be all in maven.

[image]

This was my WEB-INF/lib folder with all my jars.

Now i wanted to do the same in maven adding dependencies one by one but im having errors

When i enter a servlet i get this:

```
excepción

javax.servlet.ServletException: La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
causa raíz

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:38)
    app.Model.getProvincias(Model.java:74)
    servlet.FormS.doGet(FormS.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
causa raíz

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:25)
    app.Model.getProvincias(Model.java:74)
    servlet.FormS.doGet(FormS.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is my hibernate Configure file hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>


    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://obram2.com/obram2_base</property>


    <!--  
      <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.200.41/obram2_base</property>

    -->

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

  <property name="connection.username">obram2_root</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
  <property name="show_sql">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this my HibernateUtil

```
package util;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import bean.Business;
import bean.Client;
import bean.Form;
import bean.Pago;
public class HibernateUtil
{
    //private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static
    {
        try
        {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Localidad.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Form.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Client.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Business.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Provincia.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Pago.class);
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And Finally Here are all my new maven dependencies, which i tried to remain in same versions of all of them:

[image]

And my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>OBRAM2</groupId>
  <artifactId>OBRAM2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Remember the exact same code was working before maven, i didnt make any changes.

Thanks!

Comment: try adding this dependency also
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
 <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by creating maven folders structure. Its seems that eclipse Configure->Conver to Maven doesnt does that.

```
src\main\java
      here my files
src\main\resources
src\main\webapp
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a maven  it resolves all sub-dependencies of your artifacts and make decisions about versions of the artifacts. You can solve this conflicts by going to target/{yourapp}/WEB-INF/lib/ and see the exact jars that maven is packaging on the war. If there are some than don't fit according to your initial /lib you can use the eclipse maven dependency manager (or use  directly on the pom)  to exclude those that you don't want.

The error that you are getting is very usual when you use different versions of your artifacts.